# 99 Haskell problems, problem 18

Tags: haskell

The problem is [here](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/99_questions/11_to_20), the solutions are [here](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/99_questions/Solutions/18). I don't see a solution like mine (maybe the 4th), it seems to work though.

```
-- ---------------------------
-- 18 (**) Extract a slice from a list (idx start from 1)

slice _      _ 0 = []
slice (x:xs) 1 k = x : slice xs 1 (k-1)
slice (x:xs) i k = slice xs (i-1) (k-1)
```

I tried testing it with QuickCheck against the drop/take solution, but it gives up because of the very restrictive conditions (1 <= i <= k <= len xs) and I don't want to get deeper in testing right now.

Is this good Haskell code? Am I forgetting any edge case? (...should I suggest it on the solutions wiki?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you forgot to cover some cases.

Your compiler should be able to detect one of them. Here is what `ghc -Wall` says:

```
slice.hs:2:1: Warning:
    Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
    In an equation for `slice':
        Patterns not matched: [] _ (GHC.Types.I# #x) with #x `notElem` [0#]

slice.hs:4:8: Warning: Defined but not used: `x'
```

This version fixes those two warnings:

```
slice []     _ _ = []
slice _      _ 0 = []
slice (x:xs) 1 k = x : slice xs 1 (k-1)
slice (_:xs) i k = slice xs (i-1) (k-1)
```

But it is still incorrect, because there is another case that the compiler doesn't warn you about: a negative `k` value. Your code will return the entire list instead of an empty list.

Consequently, if you use a negative `k` on an infinite list you get an infinite loop:

```
> print $ slice [1..] 1 (-1)
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,...
```

Comment: Very exhaustive (negative `i` too is a problem). Indeed, I supposed strictly valid input. +1 also for the `-Wall` suggestion (which told me about other bad habits I was developing).